# How to use cmake to let command "pkg_check_modules" be passed in Windows with git-bash

Tags: windows, bash, cmake

I want to build [nss-pem](https://github.com/kdudka/nss-pem) on Windows by cmake with git-bash(or msys or cygwin). cmake found `pkg-config` in my cygwin's bin directory. I also added the directory path into PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and added `.pc` file and built-nss-lib into the directory I added. But I still got error when cmake exe the line `pkg_check_modules(NSS REQUIRED "nss")`

**$PKG_CONFIG_PATH**:

```
User@host MINGW64 ~/Desktop/nss-pem/build
$ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
/mingw64/lib/pkgconfig:/mingw64/share/pkgconfig
```

**CMake Error:**

```
User@host MINGW64 ~/Desktop/nss-pem/build
$ cmake ../src
-- Checking for module 'nss'
--   No package 'nss' found
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:412 (message):
  A required package was not found
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/FindPkgConfig.cmake:588 (_pkg_check_modules_internal)
  CMakeLists.txt:7 (pkg_check_modules)
```

**nss.pc:**

```
# nss pkg-config
prefix=D:/Projects/library/nss
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/WIN954.0_x86_64_64_OPT.OBJ/lib/

Name: nss
Description: The nss library
Version: 3.32
Cflags: -I${includedir}/WIN954.0_x86_64_64_OPT.OBJ/include -I${includedir}/public/nss
Libs: -L${libdir} -lnss3 -lnspr4
```

What is the correct way to build this project? And what is the best way to setup the unix-like environment to build projects on Windows?

## Update

I try to use `git-bash` and add `cygwin/bin` into my env variables. The command I used to call cmake is `cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ../src`. It seems that it occur some errors of path.

```
$ cmake -G "MSYS Makefiles" ../src
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe -- broken
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler                                                                                                             .cmake:51 (message):
  The C compiler "C:/cygwin/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test
  program.

  It fails with the following output:

   Change Dir: C:/Users/User/Desktop/nss-pem/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp



  Run Build Command:"C:/cygwin/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_bdb42/fast"

  /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_bdb42.dir/build.make
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_bdb42.dir/build

  make[1]: Entering directory
  '/cygdrive/c/Users/User/Desktop/nss-pem/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  /bin/sh: /C/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe: No such file or directory

  make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_bdb42.dir/build.make:65:
  CMakeFiles/cmTC_bdb42.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 127

  make[1]: Leaving directory
  '/cygdrive/c/Users/User/Desktop/nss-pem/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

  make: *** [Makefile:126: cmTC_bdb42/fast] Error 2





  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/User/Desktop/nss-pem/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/User/Desktop/nss-pem/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

`/bin/sh: /C/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe: No such file or directory`: bash could not find `cmake.exe`, even if I modified the `CMakeCache.txt`. And the C compiler checking always fail. (I can manually compile the test file.)

So I gave up to work with git-bash, and turn to use Windows' `cmd.exe` with `MinGW`. Below is the steps what I done.

1. Clean up `PATH` env variables (remove cygwin's dirs).
2. Copy `pkg-config.exe` and the required dynamic libraries into `MinGW/bin`.
3. Create `MinGW/lib/pkgconfig/nss.pc`.

Below is the message returned:

```
C:\Users\IvenCJ7\Desktop\nss-pem\build>cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ../src
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Found PkgConfig: C:/MinGW/bin/pkg-config.exe (found version "0.29.1")
-- Checking for module 'nss'
--   Found nss, version 3.32
-- Looking for lowkeyti.h
-- Looking for lowkeyti.h - found
-- Looking for NSSCKFWSlot_GetSlotID
-- Looking for NSSCKFWSlot_GetSlotID - not found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/User/Desktop/nss-pem/build
```

`cmake` still cannot find the function, `NSSCKFWSlot_GetSlotID` in NSS. I made sure the function is in the NSS's include headers.

Below is the information that pkg-config return to me.

```
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs nss
-ID:/Projects/library/nss/WIN954.0_x86_64_64_OPT.OBJ/include 
-ID:/Projects/library/nss/public/nss 
-LD:/Projects/library/nss/WIN954.0_x86_64_64_OPT.OBJ/lib/ -lnss3 -lnspr4
```

Comment: Does **plain** `pkg-config` (called from command line without CMake) find your package? Also, while I am not expert with `.pc` files, having relative paths in it (because `prefix` is relative) looks suspicious: If those paths will be passed to compiler, it will interpret them relative to the current dir, not to the dir with `.pc` file or so.

Comment: After I put `.pc` files into cygwin's `lib/pkgconfig/`, it finally found NSS. But it's suspicious, the path, `{cygwin}/lib/pkgconfig`, did not in my env variable, `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`. 
It seems that cygwin's `pkg-conifg` or `git-bash`(I don't know which path-translation should I follow) work on their own root-path-translation. The cmake still cannot find the function in NSS.

Comment: `The cmake still cannot find the function in NSS.` - If you want our help in resolving this problem, elaborate this phrase by updating (via [edit]) your question post. By itself, this phrase has a little sence.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I updated. Thank you!

Comment: What output of `pkg-config --cflags --libs nss` is in your environment? Having libraries copied and `.pc` file manually created looks unusual: Correctly installed package normally works without such interventions.

Comment: I updated it into the question. NSS is built by myself. In Windows I don't know is there a way to install a package.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\....` suggests you are using the wrong version of `cmake` for a bash shell.  You mentioned `msys`.  Would you be opposed to using `msys2` and using the mingw compilers that come with it? Here's a project using a similar technique.  pkgconfig is critical to this other project too, so it should do the trick. 
 https://github.com/LMMS/lmms/wiki/Dependencies-Windows#windows-os.  The relevant parts are `pacman -S git pkgconfig make cmake` which install a version prepared for the msys2 terminal.  The `C:\` paths have some problems with the bash environments.